# Access Yahoo's site and E-mail by Firefox

Tags: firefox, email, yahoo

I'm starting using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). I've had many problems to access all Yahoo's pages. Only Yahoo, others sites I access well.

I don't know why it happens! It only happens with Yahoo's pages.

Please see the images. I'm using Firefox browser. How I am new in this forum, I can't post images, then I put the URL's with them.

## Yahoo e-mail login image:

[image: Email page]

## Yahoo main page image:

[image: Main page]

The images of Yahoo pages are in Portuguese because I'm in Brazil.

I think this information is important: In my computer I have two operational systems (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04). In the Windows 7 using Firefox the Yahoo pages works normally.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen a few times.  Try this it worked for me every time:
Go to Firefox preferences, and go to the privacy tab,

[image]and click on ***clear your recent history***

and then click on ***clear now***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By experience, it could be an MTU problem. You can find the MTU setting in Network manager (ubuntu dash, search for "network", or "network connections").

1. Select your connection (Wired / Wireless)
2. Choose Edit
3. At the bottom of the page is the MTU setting, enter 1450
4. Click Save
5. Exit

In order to apply the settings, you have to restart network-manager, by executing this command in the terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

The normal, usual values of MTU for dsl connections (and ethernet/wifi) are: 1450, 1460, 1470, 1480, 1490, 1500. Try them all out.